# Why doesn't SortedDictionary call GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#

I have class `LineSegment`, which overrides `GetHashCode`:

```cs
public class LineSegment : IComparable {
    int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj) {
        ...
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        ...
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        GD.Print("Hash");
        ...
    }
}
```

And I use `LineSegment`s as keys in a `SortedDictionary`:

```cs
SortedDictionary<LineSegment, bool> sD = new SortedDictionary<LineSegment, bool>();
sD.add(new LineSegment());
```

However, `GetHashCode` is never called, not even when `SortedDictionary.Add()` complains that "An item with the same key has already been added."

If I change `SortedDictionary` to `Dictionary`, `GetHashCode` *is* called. Why?

Comment: Implement `IComparable<T>` rather than just `IComparable`

Comment: It because of the "Sorted" in SortedDictionary.  Testing for equality is not enough to sort, it needs to use IComparable.CompareTo() to provide sorted order.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot! If you would post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score -2):

`SortedDictionary` currently uses Red-black tree-like data strucutre, so instead of hashing it just repeatedly calls `CompareTo`.